# How to have a different CSS, and jQuery files for responsive version

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am really new in responsive design. I made a music player for a website. It's a plugin and I would like to make it responsive so on iPhone the layout will change (CSS), also some jQuery functions and methods such as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` will not needed, also there are some function than need to be changed copletely. How can I do that? It is just a plugin, so how can I have different jQuery and CSS files for a mobile version of a plugin?

Comment: search for media queries

Comment: If you want to get information about the user's web browser, you can detect their "user agent". It's usually better practice to use "media queries" or feature detection to only change the resources you need to change. However, if you really need to identify exactly what device the user is on, here's a tutorial explaining how to offer different resources via javascript or PHP based on the user agent: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3888106/How-Can-I-Detect-the-iPhone--iPads-User-Agent.htm

Comment: @Vincenator As far as I researched, media queries are only for CSS files. Is that right? Can't I use media queries for changing function and js files ?

Comment: @DanielJJ, you're correct that media queries are only for CSS files. A best practice is generally to avoid having separate files for different browsers; rather, you could serve the same CSS and Javascript files to all browsers but design each file to respond appropriately to different browsers. You would do that by using media queries in your CSS file and feature detection in your Javascript file.